# zgrep with large pattern file

Tags: command-line, grep, gzip, macos

I do not know a lot about the underlying process that grep goes through and I am searching with a long pattern (863 members) in a large file 646.1 MB (zipped) and it is taking some time. I thought that this would be a good time to learn more about grep.

I have several questions:

- Is it faster to unzip the file and run grep rather than leave it zipped and run zgrep?
- Does grep scale in time linearly by the number of patterns (fixed string)?
- I saw LC_ALL=C, are there any other tricks I can use to speed it up?

Comment: Could you possibly show us your command, an example of the data and an example of some of the patterns? It's usually not helpful to give advice blindly.

Comment: Re *"...it is taking some time."*: please specify how much time, on what CPU with how much RAM, and on what media the 646MB file is stored.